# Should two pictures side by side have 0.5 or 0.49999 textwidth?

Tags: graphics, syntax

Two pictures should be next to each other. What is their perfect width?
Is 0.5 + 0.5 = 1 for TeX, or does the compiler need a tiny space between the objects?

Should

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]
```

be used or better something like

```
\includegraphics[width=0.4999\textwidth]
```

in this example:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\label{a} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{a.jpg}}
  \subfloat[]{\label{b} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{b.jpg}}
  \label{fig:abpics}
  \caption{The a and the b.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: TeX is really accurate considering dimesions, but wouldn't be nicer to have some small gap in between, like `... 0.47\textwidth ... \hfill ... \0.47\textwidth ...` ?

Comment: The sum of the widths in the example is larger than `\textwidth`, because of the space after the first `\subfloat`. Put `%` next to the end: `a.jpg}}%` and LaTeX will happily put the two objects on one line.

Comment: I tried `\subfloat[]{\label{a} \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{a.jpg}}% \hfill%
  \subfloat[]{\label{b} \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{b.jpg}}` but that makes a newline between the pictures

Comment: I usually give the figures a width close to (but less than) `0.5\textwidth`, and put a `\hfill` between figures. This space expands to the required amount o align he outer edges of the figures with the page margins.

Comment: @JonasStein perhaps the space between `\label` and `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @tohecz: With `\centering`? I doubt that would work.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I guess its the best I remove `centering`. Or do you think it has still any effect on the caption?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's examine your example with care.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
```

You're starting a `figure` environment. Error: `[h]` should be `[htp]` or something.

```
  \centering
```

You want to center everything. In particular, there's no indentation at the start of the paragraphs.

```
  \subfloat[]{\label{a} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{a.jpg}}
  \subfloat[]{\label{b} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{b.jpg}}
```

These make a paragraph (boxes, as far as TeX is concerned, are just like big characters). You have an object `0.5\textwidth` wide, *a space* and another `0.5\textwidth` wide object. This makes impossible for TeX to use only one line for the paragraph. Just add a `%`:

```
  \subfloat[]{\label{a} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{a.jpg}}%
  \subfloat[]{\label{b} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{b.jpg}}
```

and the space will not be there. The width is equal to the `\textwidth` (with possible tiny errors due to the truncation of fractional numbers, where 1+1 is not always 2); if the error is by defect (of 2sp at most, which is 1/65536 of 1pt) the `\centering` declaration will add the necessary padding; if the error is by excess, the `\hfuzz` parameter usually is 0.1pt, which is way bigger than 2sp and no `Overfull \hbox` message will appear. Thus in both cases the two subfloats will appear next to each other. On the contrary, a space is usually larger than 0.1pt, thus making it impossible to set only one line.

```
  \caption{The a and the b.}
```

This makes an object independent of the above paragraph, which is terminated and typeset; then the `\caption` is typeset and all actions related to it are performed; it doesn't start a paragraph.

```
  \label{fig:abpics}
```

The `\label` contributes nothing and doesn't start a paragraph; the final space is removed anyway.

```
\end{figure}
```

The environment ends. Notice that `\label` should go *after* `\caption` in order to refer correctly to the generated number (thanks to cgnieder for remarking it).

In *very* rare cases, one might be bitten by the fact that 1+1 is not necessarily 2, when truncation of fractional numbers happens. The example is

```
\hbox to 2in{\hskip1in\hskip1in}
```

that results in an `Underfull \hbox` because the binary arithmetic used by TeX (that truncates possible fractional parts) makes 1in + 1in less than 2in by exactly 1sp. Nothing to be worried about in normal situations.

Comment: The `\label` should be placed after `\caption`, though. Also the blank between `\label{a}` and `\includegraphics` (and similar in the second subfloat) is not discarded.

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks! I wasn't looking for that!