# Subfigures side by side not working

Tags: diagrams, subfloats, two-column, subcaption

I am trying to set two figures side by side while using the `picture` environment instead of `includegraphics` as shown in most examples here. Unfortunately they are displayed stacked and I do not know what I am doing wrong. Who can help?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{2.0cm}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{picture}(1,2)
\put(0,0){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(0,1){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(1,0){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(1,1){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(0.5,1.75){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.1}}
\thicklines
\put(0,0){\vector(0,1){1}}
\put(0,1){\vector(2,3){0.5}}
\put(0.5,1.75){\vector(2,-3){0.5}}
\put(1,1){\vector(0,-1){1}}
\put(1,0){\vector(-1,0){1}}
\put(0,0){\vector(1,1){0.5}}
\put(0.5,0.5){\vector(1,1){0.5}}
\put(1,1){\vector(-1,0){1}}
\put(0,1){\vector(1,-1){0.5}}
\put(0.5,0.5){\vector(1,-1){0.5}}
\end{picture}
\caption{Euler-Path}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{picture}(1,2)
\put(0,0){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(0,1){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(1,0){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(1,1){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(0.5,1.75){\circle*{0.1}}
\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.1}}
\thicklines
\put(0,0){\vector(0,1){1}}
\put(0,1){\vector(2,3){0.5}}
\put(0.5,1.75){\vector(2,-3){0.5}}
\put(1,1){\vector(0,-1){1}}
\put(1,0){\vector(-1,1){0.5}}
\put(0.5,0.5){\vector(-1,-1){0.5}}
\end{picture}
\caption{Hammilton-Cycle}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{House of Santa Clause}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just put `%` after the first `\end{subfigure}`

Comment: The end of line counts as a space when LaTeX is typesetting a paragraph; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86417/4427) for more information.

Comment: Please shorten your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using to much width for `subfigure` package. Put the smaller multiplier (for example `0.48`) before the `\linewidth` in `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}` line.

Comment: Outch, how easy was that!? Thank you.

Comment: @hielsnoppe: No problem!

Comment: This answer is wrong. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86417/16227)