# Subfigures next to each other using subimport

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, subfloats

I want to display two subfigures next to each other (one left and one right). My problem is that they are always displayed above each other. Also I would like to use the subimport feature rather than includefigure. Unfortunatly all examples I found online however use only includefigure.

I also tried scalebox, but that didn't work: The plots are still not placed next to each other and it also scales the axis labels which I don't want. The images should be thin enough to fit next to each other.

How can I make this work with subimport?

I have tried to following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\subimport*{plots/somePath/}{plot1.tex}
\caption{sub caption 1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\subimport*{plots/somePath/}{plot2.tex}
\caption{sub caption 2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{test.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and this is the tikz code for the plot which can be used for both sub-plots for testing:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=1.5in,
height=1in,
at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
ymin=0,
ymax=10,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
0.555555555555556   1.11111111111111\\
1.11111111111111    2.22222222222222\\
1.66666666666667    3.33333333333333\\
2.22222222222222    4.44444444444444\\
2.77777777777778    5.55555555555556\\
3.33333333333333    6.66666666666667\\
3.88888888888889    7.77777777777778\\
4.44444444444444    8.88888888888889\\
5   10\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: put a `%` after `\end{subfigure}%` or reduce the width from `0.5\textwidth`.

Comment: Closely related: [Should two pictures side by side have 0.5 or 0.49999 textwidth?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86412/134144)

Comment: @nidhin omg, so simple, thanks. If you want to post it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.